# Python - GUI creates new window, but the original window is still usable. How do I stop this

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

Can anyone give me a point in the right direction please?

I've created a piece of Python code that creates a GUI.  One button opens a 'new window', but if I click on the same button again I get another 'new window', keep clicking and I've got multiple copies of the 'new window'.

I want the original window to be unaccessible whilst the 'new window' is open, and then accessible again when I close the 'new window'.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: I don't understand the closing for "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem". While the question is short, the problem is simple and somewhat obvious, and has a simple solution.

Comment: As I'm new to programming, and this site, I thought I would keep my question short and to the point without going into too much detail.  @Bryan Oakley gave me the pointers that I needed to succeed.  I apologise for my current short comings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call `grab_set()` on your new window, which will prevent any events from going to the other window. When you're done, call `grad_release()`